# How can i Implement list view load more in windows phone 8.1...?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am using json webservice after getting the responce binding to listview offset based.starting only 20 records binding after that scroll the listview again remaning records binding through offset based last id passed to service?how can i implement this feature...?
This is my code:

```
<ListView x:Name="GetallquestionListview" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Background="White" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0" Height="Auto"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource Latestitemcontainerstyle}"
                                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  Padding="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="GetallquestionListview_SelectionChanged"  >
                        <ListView.Header>
                            <ProgressBar x:Name="myIndeterminateProbar" IsIndeterminate="True" Height="50" Visibility="Collapsed"></ProgressBar>
                        </ListView.Header>

                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                                <DataTemplate>
                                <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" RequestedTheme="Light" BorderBrush="#aaBFBCBC" >
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="Auto" >
                                        <TextBlock Margin="0" x:Name="Name" Text="{Binding question_text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF110202" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" Padding="8,15,8,3" SelectionHighlightColor="White" ></TextBlock>


                                        <Image Margin="8" x:Name="image1" Source="{Binding thumbnail_path}" MaxHeight="200" Stretch="UniformToFill"></Image>

                                        <TextBlock Margin="0" x:Name="FristName" Text="{Binding total_votes}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF03A9F5" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" Padding="8,3,8,10" FontWeight="Bold" ></TextBlock>



                                    </StackPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>

                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>


                        </ListView>
```

This my code :

```
  private async void Getallquestion()
        {
            try
            {
                myIndeterminateProbar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                if (App.IsInternetAvailable)
                {
                    string Longitude = await Locations.GetLongitude();
                    string Lattitude = await Locations.GetLattitude();
                    var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
                    string Sortigntype;

                    // Create a simple setting
                    Object value = localSettings.Values["Login_Data"];
                    string UserId = value.ToString();
                    //Calling Webservice
                    string QuestionsList = await WebServices.GetAllQuestionByoffset(Convert.ToInt32(UserId), 20, Lastoffsetindex, LastquestionId, Convert.ToDouble(Lattitude), Convert.ToDouble(Longitude), lastsyncime, 1);

                    if (QuestionsList != null)
                    {
                        DataContractJsonSerializer obj1 = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(UserMessage));
                        UserMessage Questionstatusobject = obj1.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(QuestionsList))) as UserMessage;

                        string StatusId = Questionstatusobject.status_id.ToString();
                        string Message = Questionstatusobject.message;
                        if (StatusId == "1")
                        {

                            JObject retun_json = JObject.Parse(QuestionsList);

                            JToken token = JToken.Parse(QuestionsList);
                            JArray questionss = (JArray)token.SelectToken("questions");

                            string votetext;
                            for (int i = 0; i < questionss.Count; ++i)
                            {
                                Questions ques = new Questions();
                                //  string questiontext;
                                //if (questionss[i]["question_text"].ToString() == "")
                                //{
                                //    ques.question_text = questionss[i]["question_text"].ToString();
                                //}
                                //else
                                //{
                                //   questiontext = Locations.EncodeDecodeBase64(questionss[i]["question_text"].ToString());

                                //}
                                //  ques.question_text = Locations.EncodeDecodeBase64(ques.question_text);
                                ques.question_text = Locations.DecodeFrom64(questionss[i]["question_text"].ToString());
                                // ques.question_text = questionss[i]["question_text"].ToString();
                                ques.thumbnail_path = questionss[i]["thumbnail_path"].ToString();
                                ques.question_id = Convert.ToInt32(questionss[i]["question_id"]);
                                ques.user_id = Convert.ToInt32(questionss[i]["user_id"]);
                                if (questionss[i]["total_votes"].ToString() == "1")
                                {
                                    votetext = "Vote";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    votetext = "Votes";
                                }
                                ques.total_votes = questionss[i]["total_votes"] + " " + votetext;
                                GetallquestionListview.Items.Add(ques);
                                GetAllquestionsdata.Add(ques);

                            }





                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageDialog msgbox2 = new MessageDialog("" + Message + "");
                            await msgbox2.ShowAsync();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageDialog msgbox = new MessageDialog("Oops! something went wrong. Please try again.");
                        await msgbox.ShowAsync();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageDialog msgbox = new MessageDialog("Please check your Internet connection.");
                    await msgbox.ShowAsync();
                }
                 }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {

                }
            myIndeterminateProbar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to check for `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface. check out this

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.isupportincrementalloading%28v=win.10%29.aspx

This is an example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/228873/Loading-Data-when-the-User-Scrolls-to-the-End-of

Comment: Thaks i will follow above links .if any case found bugs i will get back to u thanku very much. i you have free time please provide some steps implement the lode more in my above code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface in your collection.

The MSDN provides an [example implementation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh701916)

```
public class BaseIncrementalObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    #region ISupportIncrementalLoading

    public bool HasMoreItems
    {
        get { return HasMoreItemsOverride(); }
    }

    public Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
    {
        if (_busy)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Only one operation in flight at a time");
        }

        _busy = true;

        return AsyncInfo.Run((c) => LoadMoreItemsAsync(c, count));
    }

    #endregion 

    #region INotifyCollectionChanged

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    #endregion 

    #region Private methods

    async Task<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(CancellationToken c, uint count)
    {
        try
        {
            var items = await LoadMoreItemsOverrideAsync(c, count);
            var baseIndex = _storage.Count;

            _storage.AddRange(items);

            // Now notify of the new items
            NotifyOfInsertedItems(baseIndex, items.Count);

            return new LoadMoreItemsResult { Count = (uint)items.Count };
        }
        finally
        {
            _busy = false;
        }
    }

    void NotifyOfInsertedItems(int baseIndex, int count)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var args = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, _storage[i + baseIndex], i + baseIndex);
            CollectionChanged(this, args);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Overridable methods

    protected abstract Task<IList<T>> LoadMoreItemsOverrideAsync(CancellationToken c, uint count);
    protected abstract bool HasMoreItemsOverride();

    #endregion 

    #region State

    List<T> _storage = new List<T>();
    bool _busy = false;

    #endregion
}
```

Then you can derive from this and implement the concrete requests.

```
public class UserIncrementalObservableCollection : BaseIncrementalObservableCollection<User>
{
    protected override Task<IList<User>> LoadMoreItemsOverrideAsync(CancellationToken c, uint count) 
    {
        // your call to the webservice
    }
    protected override bool HasMoreItemsOverride() 
    {
        // check if there are more
    }

}
```

Alternatively, pass `Func<CancellationToken, uint, IList<T>>` and `Func<bool>` delegates into your class, so you can avoid implementing dozens of concrete classes if there is a big number of incremental lists.

Comment: Thanks for u r responce but i can not understand how can i implement that one i am sharing my code please add some steps...

Comment: Thaks i will follow above links .if any case  found bugs i will get back to u thanku very much.

Comment: Check out this implementation of `ISupportIncrementalLoading` at https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/implementing-the-isupportincrementalloading-interface-in-a-window-store-app/. You'll have to do some work by yourself, we can't do everything for you. You asked how to solve the problem, not "do my work for me".

Comment: Sorry ...Tseng i will study on that links will solve my problem.